# Suppose $0 \leq u_n \leq v_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that if $v_n$ converges to zero, then $u_n$ converges to zero.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

So I have an idea of how to do this and I want to make sure I'm right. Here is my attempt:

Proof:

Given: $v_n$ converges to zero.

In other words: for all $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ there exists a natural number $N$, for all naturals $n$, such that if $n\geq N$ then $|v_n - 0| < \epsilon$.

Note that $0\leq u_n \leq v_n$ implies $0\leq |u_n| \leq |v_n|$, so we get:

$\epsilon > |v_n - 0| = |v_n| \geq |u_n| = |u_n - 0|$.

Therefore, for all $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ there exists a natural number $N$, for all naturals $n$, such that if $n\geq N$ then $|u_n - 0| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @xhsbm No problem with the proof, but what is the point of using $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q} ^+$?

Comment: @PierreCarre Because we're still constructing the reals.

Answer (score 1):

since $\forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\ 0 \le u_n \le v_n => 0 \le lim_{n->\infty} u_n \le lim_{n->\infty} v_n = 0 => lim_{n->\infty} u_n  = 0$