# Is this right or wrong?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is this right or wrong ?

if $\;\;U_n \geq U_1 \geq V_n  
\; \; \text{and} \;\;\lim{U_n}=\lim{V_n} =a \geq 0$

this is implies $\;\; U1 =a$

I think it's true but I'm not sure .

Let := $X_n=U_1$

$\;\;U_n \geq X_n \geq V_n  
\; \;  \text{and} \;\;\lim{U_n}=\lim{V_n} =a \implies \lim X_n = a  = U_1$

Comment: this is right but always show your thoughts first

Comment: Show that $|U_1-V_n| \le |U_n-V_n|$.

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: $$U_n \geq V_n \\ U_1 \geq V_n  \\  U_n \geq U_1  \\ \text{this implies} \; \;|U_1-V_n| \le |U_n-V_n| $$

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first show $U_1\geq a$.

suppose not then $U_1<a$ let $\epsilon = a - U_1>0$ then there exists $N$ such that $|V_n-a|<a-U_1$. That means $a-V_n<a-U_1$ and so $U_1<V_n$. Contradiction.

Similarly $U_1\leq a$. QED.

Comment: Finally, we find that :$U_1\geq a \; \; \text{and} \; \;U_1 \leq a \implies U_1=a$

Comment: @مصطفىمصطفى yep

Comment: This site is great, thank you

Comment: @مصطفىمصطفى No problem, this question here that I saw https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3867995/suppose-0-leq-u-n-leq-v-n-for-all-n-in-mathbbn-prove-that-if-v-n-con?rq=1 is also similar.

Comment: Nice question ،